# Return to index page from the contact page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I have one long index page with sections and one contact page, but the problem is if you will go to the contact page and want to go back to the long index page, the navigation links are corrputed.

This is my navigation:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">STUDIO</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#team" class="smoothScroll">TEAM</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#service" class="smoothScroll">SERVICES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#work" class="smoothScroll">WORK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#pricing" class="smoothScroll">PRICING</a></li>
                            @*<li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">CONTACT</a></li>*@
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

so if you now go to the contact page, the url wil be:

```
http://localhost:53534/Home/Contact
```

but if you want to go from there for example to: services, you will get the url:

```
http://localhost:53534/Home/Contact#service - what is not the correct url, because the correct url has to be:

http://localhost:53534/#service. So without the controller name contact.
```

But how to manage that?

Thank you

oke, I tried, like this:

```
                           @Html.ActionLink( "Contact", "Contact"
                        , "Home"
                        , Request.Url.Scheme
                        , Request.Url.Host
                        , "contact"
                        , null
                        , null
                        )
                        </li>
```

but then again if you go from contact to other link, you will get this:
http://localhost:53534/Home/Contact#pricing

I also tried this:

```
                           @Html.ActionLink( "Contact", "Contact"
                        , "Home"
                        , Request.Url.Scheme
                        , Request.Url.Host
                        , ""
                        , null
                        , null
                        )
                        </li>
```

so my full navigation looks like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">STUDIO</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#team" class="smoothScroll">TEAM</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#service" class="smoothScroll">SERVICES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#work" class="smoothScroll">WORK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#pricing" class="smoothScroll">PRICING</a></li>

                            <li>

                               @Html.ActionLink( "Contact", "Contact"
                            , "Home"
                            , Request.Url.Scheme
                            , Request.Url.Host
                            , "contact"
                            , null
                            , null
                            )
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

This is the newest:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">HOME</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">STUDIO</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#team" class="smoothScroll">TEAM</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#service" class="smoothScroll">SERVICES</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#work" class="smoothScroll">WORK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#pricing" class="smoothScroll">PRICING</a></li>

                                <li>

                                   @Html.ActionLink( "Contact", "Contact"
                                , "Home"
                                , Request.Url.Scheme
                                , Request.Url.Host
                                , "contact"
                                , null
                                , null
                                )
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

but then the link will become:http://localhost:53534/Home/Contact#pricing. and it should be: http://localhost:53534/Home/#pricing.

Yes, ok, sorry for that, wrong post, but:

```
                            @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Index"
                            , "Home"
                            , Request.Url.Scheme
                            , Request.Url.Host
                            , "contact"
                            , null
                            , null
                            )
                        </li> The contact page has to be without "#". But now this is with "#". So how to omit the "#"? I just changed the first Index to Contact, because that is just the name
```

Comment: Use the [overload of Html.ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492938(v=vs.118).aspx) that accepts a fragment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121272/return-to-index-page-from-the-contact-page/30121337#comment48352838_30121272), you could use this overload of [`Html.ActionLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492938(v=vs.118).aspx).

```
@Html.ActionLink
( "Index"
, "Index"
, "Home"
, null
, null
, "contact" // the fragment
, null
, null
);
```

Else you could use regular anchor (`a`) elements in HTML and an `@Url.Action`. You could use `Url.Action` to get to the main page and navigate further from there:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")#some_optional_hash" />
```

Comment: Note also you can use `null` in place of both `Request.Url.Scheme` and `Request.Url.Host` to use the defaults.

Comment: Yes, ok, sorry for that, wrong post, but: <li>

                                @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Index"
                                , "Home"
                                , Request.Url.Scheme
                                , Request.Url.Host
                                , "contact"
                                , null
                                , null
                                )
                            </li> The contact page has to be without "#". But now this is with "#". So how to omit the "#"?

Comment: So like this:  <li>

                                @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Index"
                                , "Home"
                                , Request.Url.Scheme
                                , Request.Url.Host
                                ,"" 
                                , null
                                , null
                                )
                            </li>

Comment: But then the url will be of contact: http://localhost:53534/ like this: <li>

                                @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Index"
                                , "Home"
                                , Request.Url.Scheme
                                , Request.Url.Host
                                ,"" 
                                , null
                                , null
                                )
                            </li>

Comment: @hallohallo: That is the general URL right? Does it work if you click it?

Comment: But that doesnt work. It doesnt go to the contact page, it goes to the root of the site: http://localhost:53534/

Comment: You have to apply that to `#home` and all the other parts on the main page. Then apply the `Contact` action on the contact page.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty workaround is to just set the anchors' href attributes to absolute, rather than to relative paths, e.g.:

```
<li><a href="/#pricing" class="smoothScroll">PRICING</a></li>
```

Comment: Hi SWeko, thank you. But Just also interested in the relative linking way. Do you know that?

Comment: This might go wrong with applications that don't run in the web server's root.